# Equality of two eigenspaces of a regular transition matrix corresponding to the eigenvalue 1.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue of a $n\times n$ regular transition matrix $A$. Then there is some $m\in\Bbb N$ such that all entries of  $A^m$ are positive.

I want to ask how to prove $E_\lambda=E'_\lambda$, where $E_\lambda$ is the eigenspace of $A$ and $E'_\lambda$ is the eigenspace of $A^m$.

I know $E_\lambda\subset E'_\lambda$ is true and $\text{dim}(E'_\lambda)=1$, how to prove the converse?

Comment: you just need to prove that there's $\lambda=1$ has no non-trinvial Jordan block, and that there are no other eigenvalues with modulo $1$

Comment: Is there another elementary way to show that, I'm just read the context of diagonalization .

Comment: What's the dimension of $E_\lambda$?

Comment: $\text{dim}(E_\lambda)=1$

Comment: A vector space of dimension 1 has exactly 1 vector subspace of dimension 1, namely itself.  You know $E_\lambda\subseteq E_\lambda'$ and both have dimension 1, so $E_\lambda=E_\lambda'$.

Comment: thanks, I got it!